# Get values in the same line sql

Tags: sql

I want to retrieve two amounts with a query.
To be more specific I have a table with saved amounts called TABLE1 with values as follows :

```
   TABLE1
   ------------------
   | ID   |  AMOUNT |
   ------------------
   | 100  | 100.2   |
   | 511  | 400.1   |
   | 730  | 200.7   |
   ------------------
```

And another table which have for a specific id a flg value Y

```
    TABLE2
    ----------------------------
    | comb_nbr   |  ID   | FLG  |
    ----------------------------
    |   10       | 511   |   N  |
    |   10       | 100   |   Y  |
    |   10       | 730   |   N  |
    ----------------------------
```

I want to get output as follows

```
     Desired Output
     --------------------------------
     | TABLE1_AMOUNT | TABLE2_AMOUNT |
     --------------------------------
     | 100.2      |  100.2           |
     ---------------------------------
```

I am using the following query to get the values.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN id =  :p_amount_id THEN amount END) AS TABLE1_AMOUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN id != :p_amount_id THEN amount END) AS TABLE2_AMOUNT
FROM table1
WHERE col_nbr = :p_column_nbr 
AND   line_nbr = :p_line_nbr 
AND  (id = :p_amount_id
      OR id IN (SELECT id
                  FROM table2
                 WHERE comb_nbr = 10
                   AND flg = 'Y'));
```

The issue I deal is that if subquery returns the same id with the bind_variable :p_amount_id
then the TABLE2_AMOUNT is null. (DUE to Or operator)
Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: ,Which DBMS are you using.Why TABLE1_AMOUNT ,TABLE2_AMOUNT have same value..?

Comment: :p_amount_id can not be equal and different than something at same time, of course one of them returns null.

Comment: @ Fran Cerezo different than something is used for ordering reasons.
I want the value of the subquery to be displayed second.